# is the patch-size the area of the patch?

Tags: pixel, netlogo, patch

I have a question regarding patch size. Patch size is "measured in pixels."

When `patch-size` is equal to 2, does this number means the width of a patch in pixels (i.e. 2 pixels x 2 pixels) or the area of the patch (i.e.patch occupies 2 pixels)?

Comment: Patch size in the length of one side of a square.  Values less than 1 won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. so the area of the patch is patch-size^2?

Comment: @shima Yes. Area of each patch is `patch-size` squared.

Comment: @Masoud, thanks for the respone!